# Plugin System for symfony2

Tags: symfony, plugins

Is there a known tutorial that shows how to create a plugin system for symfony2?
Something like the big cms' have, a folder in the root directory where you can place your plugins.
Google just made a fool with me because the symfony1 bundles were called "plugins".
I imagine plugins to be just bundles, but not in the `src` but in the new `plugins` one.
They should be registered at runtime.

Comment: Are you looking for [bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html)?

Comment: I am looking for something that loads bundles from an different directory, and if possible at runtime.

Comment: Bundles are usually stored in the `vendor` directory and you can add/remove them by editing your `composer.json` file and running `composer.phar update/install`.

Comment: Of course, but this is what I am searching for, a script that loads bundles from a `plugins` directory. The only thing I imagine is to crawl the directory from within the `AppKernel`.

Comment: What should these plugins provide?

Comment: These "plugins" should be handled as boundles internally, because it may expand the application with templates etc. . But mainly a plugin should consist of event listeners.

Comment: I think this is not supported natively by symfony 2 but You could use vendor folder and code some function to find and register bundles automatically that are in vendor folder, or create new folder and declare it in composer autoload.

Comment: @YakobeYak I'm afraid not, but you could have a look at this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9341

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Event Dispatcher from Symfony to achive want you want. The below link might help you.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html

I don't have any guide to explain how to use this for plugin system as I am personally looking for it.